# Writing to a .txt file if input is not matching a certain format

Tags: format, notepad

My set task is to make my program write to a .txt file if the input entered is not matching the certain format,in this case being the format of a standard UK registration plate. However the outcome always seems to be only the first if statement, as if the 'else' is ignored. This is what it looks like.

```
import re

NumberP = open('NumberP.txt','a')
plate = 'AB12 ABC'
question = input('Please enter your number plate. ')
if re.match(r'^[A-Z][A-Z]\d\d [A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]$', plate):
   print ("The Plate matches Standard UK Plate")
else:
   print("ERROR")
   Number.write(question)
NumberP.close()
```

If anyone can help me fix this would be great.

Comment: 1. What is the question? 2. Add `python` tag.

Comment: Sorry my bad, added it.

Comment: You are trying to match `plate`, while you should match `question` i.e. user input.